# Jenkins - Android Emulator Plugin - Location of AVD

Tags: android-emulator, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins 1.495 on mac OSx 10.7.4. I am trying to configure Android Emulator Plugin.

In the Job configuration (advanced project options), I specified  'use customer workspace'-> Directory, which is "/users/testuser/androidws/HelloWorld". This is where my android project is located.

I then selected "Run an Android Emulator during build" and selected "Run existing emulator" and I gave the name of existing avd. Jenkins is looking for this AVD file in "/users/testuser/androidws/HelloWorld/.android/avd", rather it should look for "$HOME/.android/avd".

I didn't find any option to force Jenkins to look in $HOME/.android/avd folder.

I am running Jenkins as daemon with real user which has HOME directory.

Any ideas are appreciated..

Thanks

- Forgot to mention if I tried with "Run emulator with options" (creating new emulator) option works but it creates .android/avd folder in my project. Basically Jenkins is not looking for .android/avd in $HOME which is the problem that I am trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you enabled the "Create emulators in the workspace" option in the Jenkins system configuration.

Turn that off and it should work.

Though the plugin should be fixed to do that automatically if you select the "Use existing emulator" option.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see any option 'create emulators in the workspace" in the job configuration page.

Comment: The option is called "Keep emulators in the job workspace, in the .android subdirectory, to isolate them as much as possible", under Manage Jenkins -> Configure System.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr: Looks like we have the same/similar problem as OP. Is it possible to tell the plugin that the AVDs (created on the fly) are under Jenkins' home dir (`/var/lib/jenkins/`), without resorting to hacks like `ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins`?

Comment: @Jonik Probably not, as Jenkins is just running the Android tools, and it's the Android tools that are checking for the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` variable. A possibility could be to make the `~${JENKINS_USER}/.android` directory a symlink to `/var/lib/jenkins`.